# Where to get Spring Heeled double-jump Trinket?

Tags: deathloop

I just beat the first mission Ubiquity (Wenjie) Visionary. For some reason, I sacrificed the Spring Heeled double-jump Trinket. Now I want to go on to the second mission Chaos Theory (Harriet) Visionary. But I don't have the double-jump trinket. Everyone says that it's where you first wake up but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first couple of loops it is directly in front of you when you enter the bunker on the beach.

[image: Screenshot of the game]

The loop after you complete Ubiquity is the last time you play the beach section. After that, it's automatically in your inventory at the start of every loop, even if you sacrificed it.

Comment: but i was not able to double jump, do i need pick up something?

Comment: You need to equip it in your loadout.